# How to flatten hierarchical XML file using XSLT stylesheet with namespace in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling with XSLT and XML...quite new in this arena.

I have a multi-level (hierarchical) XML file that I need to flatten. I've build my very first XSLT file and it worked with a XML file I had created for development. However, it keeps failing when I'm pointing it to the intended XML file. I've found that it works if I delete the namespace from the XML file. I've also tried to prefix the namespace in the XSLT file but couldn't get that to work either.

After hours of searching the internet, and trying all kinds of fixes...I finally have to pull over and ask for directions.

I've added a small snippet of the XSLT file where I try to select "LoadID" and also the XML file below.

XSLT:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="LoadExtractRecords">
        <xsl:for-each select="LoadExtractRecords/LoadExtractRecord">
            <xsl:element name="LoadExtractRecord">
                <xsl:element name="LoadID">
                    <xsl:value-of select="LoadID"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LoadExtractRecords xmlns="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load">
  <LoadExtractRecord>
    <LoadID>41955711</LoadID>
    <Company id="14188">COMPANY NAME</Company>
    <ShipperLoadRef>41955711</ShipperLoadRef>
    <Status id="1071">COMPLETED</Status>
    <Type id="1525">LOAD</Type>
    <LoadGroup id="63617">RESTOCK</LoadGroup>
    <Contact id="86226">
        <FirstName>Jennifer</FirstName>
        <LastName>Benson</LastName>
        <UserName>jenniferbenson</UserName>
    </Contact>
    <CreateDate>2011-08-28T20:56:19-04:00</CreateDate>
  </LoadExtractRecord>
</LoadExtractRecords>
```

The XSLT above produces the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoadExtractRecords xmlns="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load" />
```

When I delete the namespace in the XML file, I get the intended result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LoadExtractRecords xmlns="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load">
  <LoadExtractRecord>
    <LoadID>41955711</LoadID>
  </LoadExtractRecord>
</LoadExtractRecords>
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a **prefix** to the namespace and use it when addressing elements in the source document. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ld="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load"
exclude-result-prefixes="ld">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <LoadExtractRecords xmlns="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load">
        <xsl:for-each select="ld:LoadExtractRecords/ld:LoadExtractRecord">
            <LoadExtractRecord>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ld:LoadID"/>
            </LoadExtractRecord>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </LoadExtractRecords>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ld="http://www.leanlogistics.com/DESchema/load"
exclude-result-prefixes="ld">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/ld:LoadExtractRecords">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="ld:LoadExtractRecord">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ld:LoadID"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note:
1. you don't need to use `xsl:element` when the name of the element is known;
2. there's no XML version 2.0;
3. this is not really "flattening".

Comment: Thank you so much @michael.hor257k . You can count on a free beer if you should ever come to the Raleigh area USA. Regarding your notes,  I was influenced by this blog: [link](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/21-XML-Task-Changing-Style-of-Data-XSLT.html). He used xls:element and version 2.0. I agree only pulling LoadID is not flattening, but there is no way I could even get to flatten anything before I could get data from top of the hierarchy. I'm hoping I can take it from here on my own. The original XML file has 8 lvl in total so I'm sure it's going to be fun. Thank you so much!